# Couldn't call function after set them as variable in if statement - Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a multi-function for validation inputs and i don't call a master function before checking these inputs and validate them

so I have a "master function" **SignUp Function** and inside it, I set a validation function as a vars and check it before passing to other rest of function so the validation is invoked very well but I can't see other rest is invoked and my DB is empty

```
// sample of validations Func
handleUsername = () => {
    const {userName} = this.state;
    if (userName.length <= 0) {
      this.setState({
        NameValid: 'من فضللك قم بكتابة اسمك',
      });
      return;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        NameValid: '',
      });
    }
}


signUpFunc = async () => {
    console.log('im here');
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    // For Validations Inputs
    const nameValid = this.handleUsername();
    const emailValid = this.handleEmail();
    const phoneValid = this.handlePhone();
    const passwordValid = this.handlePassword();

    if (!nameValid || !phoneValid || !emailValid || !passwordValid) {
      console.log('Validations statment here');
      return;
    } else {
      console.log('else statment'); // i can't see this in my console after validated
      console.log('email', email);
      console.log('password', password);
      await auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('done');
          this.setState({loading: true}, () => this.createUserDatabase());
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          switch (errorCode) {
            case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
              alert('هذا البريد مستخدم من قبل ، جرب بريد أخر');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
              alert('الريد الإلكتروني غير صالح، جرب بريد آخر');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
            case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':
              alert('هذا البريد معطل من قبل إدارة التطبيق');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
            case 'auth/weak-password':
              alert('كلمة المرور ضعيفة');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
            default:
              alert('تحقق من اتصال الانترنت لديك');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
          }
        });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you use `if` and `else`, the code will execute only the `if` or the `else`, so:

```js
if (true) {
  console.log('Here'); // enters here
} else {
  console.log('Not here'); // so don't enter here
}
```

The first condition will execute only.

Second thing, if you assigned a function to a variable, e don't return nothing from this function, this variable will be `false`, like this:

```js
function example() {
  return;
}

const variable = example();

if(!variable) { // false, but you use `not`, so it's true
  console.log('is true');
}
```

If you want to check, if something is valid or not, return `true` or `false` from your function, like this:

```js
function example() {
  if(1 === 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const variable = example();
console.log(variable);
```

So, in your code, you may want something like this:

```js
// sample of validations Func
handleUsername = () => {
    const {userName} = this.state;
    if (userName.length <= 0) {
      this.setState({
        NameValid: 'من فضللك قم بكتابة اسمك',
      });
      return false; // is it's invalid, return false
    } else {
      this.setState({
        NameValid: '',
      });
      return true; // else, return true
    }
}


signUpFunc = async () => {
    console.log('im here');
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    // For Validations Inputs
    const nameValid = this.handleUsername();
    const emailValid = this.handleEmail();
    const phoneValid = this.handlePhone();
    const passwordValid = this.handlePassword();

    if (nameValid || phoneValid || emailValid || passwordValid) {
      console.log('Validations statment here');
      
      // So if any validator is true, the code below will execute
      console.log('else statment'); 
      console.log('email', email);
      console.log('password', password);
      await auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('done');
          this.setState({loading: true}, () => this.createUserDatabase());
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          switch (errorCode) {
            case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
              alert('هذا البريد مستخدم من قبل ، جرب بريد أخر');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
              alert('الريد الإلكتروني غير صالح، جرب بريد آخر');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
            case 'auth/operation-not-allowed':
              alert('هذا البريد معطل من قبل إدارة التطبيق');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
            case 'auth/weak-password':
              alert('كلمة المرور ضعيفة');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
            default:
              alert('تحقق من اتصال الانترنت لديك');
              this.setState({loading: false, password: ''});
              break;
          }
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for reply that's a perfect answer but when i invoke the signUpFunc() the code inside if statement invoked i mean "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" and i don't do that if inputs are empty

Comment: OH that's my bad because in a // is it's valid, return true should return false cuz it's not valid

Comment: I edited the post and inverted the return of validator. So, if the `username` is empty, it will return false, else will return true.